# dot command (.) not found on FreeBSD 9.3

Tags: linux, shell, freebsd

On `FreeBSD 9.3`, I tried to used the dot command (`.`) on the `root` user (root@myserver#) but I received the following error:

```
> .: Command not found.
```

However, as a 'non-root` (#) user it works fine! What is going on?

$PATH - i point to /root and now ,i test on ec2 freebsd 9.3 dot command (.) is work but build server target on virsualbox can't found

I solve by use 'su username_root_login' and dot command (.) is work perfectly.

Comment: What shell is root using versus the other user? Is one `(t)csh` and another `bash`?

Comment: How does the 'PATH' env variable for root user look as ?

Comment: @cmidi: `$PATH` is irrelevant; `.` is a built-in command (for sh, bash, ksh, zsh, et al).

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks for letting me know. You even learn from your wrong comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` ("dot") command is built into the Bourne shell (`sh`) and into shells derived from it (`bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, etc.).  It reads and executes commands from a specified file. Unlike executing a file as a script, `.` executes the commands in the context of the current shell process. In some shells, `source` is equivalent to `.`.

`csh` and its derivative `tcsh` do *not* have `.` as a built-in command. They do have an equivalent `source` command -- but that's not likely to be a solution, since either `. filename` or `source filename` executes commands *in the current shell process*, and the commands have to be valid for the current shell. `sh` and `csh` are similar for some simple commands, but for anything complex (`if` statements, loops, some kinds of I/O redirection, etc.) they implement incompatible languages. If you have a script meant to be executed from `sh` or `bash` using `. filename`, you won't be able to execute from `csh` or `tcsh`, even by using `source filename`.

You're probably getting the error because the `root` account's default shell is `/bin/csh` or `/bin/tcsh` (I think that's typical for BSD-based systems). Your own non-`root` account probably has some Bourne-based shell as its default. You can find out what your default shell is by typing `echo $SHELL` at a prompt.

On my system, I get a different error message when I try to use `. filename` from a `csh` or `tcsh` prompt but you could have a version that behaves differently.

That explains why you're getting an error. It doesn't tell you how to fix it, but you haven't really given us enough information for that. If you really need to source a file, you have to be running a shell that's compatible with the commands in that file. You might need to execute, say, `/bin/bash` from the root shell prompt and then use the `.` command. But without more information, I can't tell whether that makes sense.

What script are you trying to source? What is it supposed to do? Are you sure it needs to be sourced rather than executed?